# CSS Dropdown with Absolute Position Overflow Scrollable Parent

Tags: css, position, css-position, overflow, absolute

I am trying to create a section of a site where there are dropdown menus within a scrollable section. The scrollable section overflows in the Y direction since it will have an unknown number of items. Each item has its own dropdown which is positioned absolutely.

Ideally in this demo (link below), clicking on lines 11 or 12 I would be able to have the absolutely positioned dropdown not respect the overflow of the parent (ie it doesnt get cut off). Is that possible to achieve?

https://ik9u2.csb.app/

*edit* original codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-noether-ik9u2

Answer (score 0):

Change the dropdown-item class to fixed position to prevent it from being hidden by the scroll

Then to align the dropdown with the button, remove the top and left values set for the dropdown-item class and set the dropdown class for the span to inline-block to make the dropdown window appear below the button
If you want to leave the dropdown window over the button as you have it now , use inline-grid instead